# Export data from DHIS2 with link between parent and child tables?

Tags: dhis2, export

We are trying to export a “parent table” if we can call it so, with its “child table”.
Both are connected using a relationship type. When data is added in the parent table, the user can go to the relation tab and add more data, which is working great.

The problem is with the export. The data is being exported separately with NO link or connection between them. We are using an online server for DHIS2 so we don’t have direct access to the database structure.

If this problem is solved, we are ready to go with DHIS2 for the final stage of implementation. And the connection between those 2 tables is sensitive.

How can we export data from both tables with a link/key connection between both tables?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about databases.  You could possiblly ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but you would certainly have to specify what DB you are using.  Read their https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to make sure you know the rules.

Comment: No, this question is not about dbs. Please @StephenOstermiller read the question. DHIS2 does not have a clear method on how to export data from its web app with any related data (using the relation ships) and I am asking about it.